# image not displayed?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display an image from database.There were no errorin code   Could anybody help me to sort it out?

```
   //Model

 function getImage()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->db->where('user_id',$id);
        $r=$this->db->get('tbl_usrs');
        if($r->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach ($r -> result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $r->free_result();
        return $data; //error
    }


 Controller
public function index() {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_login')) {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('sessiondata');
        $id = $session_data['user_id'];
        $this->load->model('Display_profilepicture');
        $data = $this->Display_profilepicture->getImage();
        //print_r($data);
        $img = base_url().$data;
        $data=array('profile_picture'=>$img);
        //$this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('my_profile',array('data'=>$data));
            }

view
      <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="<?php echo base_url('Profile_pic/index') ?>" class="pull-right"><img title="profile image" class="img-circle img-responsive" src="<?php echo isset( $img) ?>"></a>
```

this is result of my var_dump result 
 array(1) { ["profile_picture"]=> string(70) "http://localhost/ko//upload/large/c4bd859f588751f33c0dfd0907bbff24.jpg" }

Comment: In your controller, change

$this->load->view('your_view',$data)

to

$this->load->view('your_view',array('data' => $data));

When you do $this->load->view('view', $variable) it takes $variable and uses the php function extract() to turn the array keys into variables. So, if you want to use the variable $data in a nested view, you have to send another array like I did above.

Comment: errors are still the same..

Comment: It should work, but to test, please do this: In your  view, put die(var_dump($data)); as the first line, and see what it outputs.Debugging helps always

Comment: Problem with your code is that you try to echo value which is empty...

Comment: what is the structure of `tbl_usrs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are calling a variable named `$img` yet you are not setting it anywhere above the reference.

`$data=array('profile_picture'=>$img);`

Further, you are calling a variable which again is undefined in the view.

And finally you are not `echo`ing the variable:

`src="<?php echo $img ?>"`

Try setting the variable `$img` to something and this will resolve your issue.

Here are a couple of references to learning variables and understanding how they work.

- [PHP: Basics - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)
- [PHP 5 Variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp)

Comment: @paritosh In order for a variable to work, it needs to hold a value. Take a look at the reference I added to help better understand variables.

Comment: i am assigning key $img to profile_picture that's right or it means something else......

Comment: @paritosh yes, I see that you are assigning that, but the problem is, `$img` doesn't hold a value. If you are looking for something more along the lines of `$data['img']` that would be more correct. But I do not know the output of your `$data` array.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => 26 [first_name] => aman [last_name] => [username] => aman123 [sex] => [dob] => 0000-00-00 [phone] => 0 [email] => aman@gmail.com [visited_country] => 0 [about_me] => [help_others] => [fav_activity] => [bed_offer] => 0 [couch_country] => 0 [couch_state] => 0 [couch_city] => 0 [couch_addline1] => [couch_addline2] => [profile_picture] => /upload/large/637bc03ae2867f5bcf586d4a1b384788.jpg  its some thing like this i tried $data['img'] but it didn't resolved..

Comment: `$data['img']` was just an example - I had no idea if it would work or not - as I stated, I did not know your output for `$data`. It appears that your image is being set, thus update your `src="<?php $img ?>"` to be `src="<?php echo $profile_picture; ?>"`

Comment: replacing view  didn't help it does not echo anything but the error $img undefined replacing this error would my profile pic will be displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86524/discussion-between-paritosh-and-rhapx).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Model

    function getImage()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $this->db->where('user_id',$id);
        $r=$this->db->get('tbl_usrs');
        $data = array();
        if($r->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach ($r -> result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $r->free_result();
        return $data;
    }


 Controller
public function index() {
        if($this->session->userdata('is_login')) {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('sessiondata');
        $id = $session_data['user_id'];
        $this->load->model('Display_profilepicture');
        $data = $this->Display_profilepicture->getImage();
        //print_r($data);
        $img = base_url().$data['profile_picture'];
        $data=array('profile_picture'=>$img);
        //$this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('my_profile',$data);
            }

view
      <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="<?php echo base_url('Profile_pic/index') ?>" class="pull-right"><img title="profile image" class="img-circle img-responsive" src="<?php echo $profile_picture; ?>"></a>
```